# Unable to apt-get update, Synaptic for apt and muon does not start, no way even using a terminal

Tags: apt, updates, synaptic

I am pretty new using Linux and use to mess up my system testing and trying. 
So, synaptic does not start as all I have to get packets and updates.

Here is error's message I had (English isn't my mother language, be kind with my level please)

```
E: Erreur syntaxique /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/apt-file.conf:17 : valeur suivie de choses illicites
```

Translation from the french is `:value followed by illicit things` !! Ooops
What are illicit things ? I am not a bandit.
I checked `etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, here is the file :

```
# Apt-file configuration file

# Substitutions are made as follows:
#   host => remote hostname
#   port => remote port
#   uri => complete URI from sources.list
#   path => path from /
#   dist => the distribution name
#   cache => path to the local cache dir
#   dest => the destination file name inside the cache dir
#   cdrom => cdrom mount point

# Where are located Packages
destination = <host>_<path>_dists_<dist>_Contents-<arch>.gz

# common code blocks can be defined as variables and be used as $check_cmd, etc. later
check_cmd = ( ( gunzip -l "<cache>/<dest>_tmp" >/dev/null 2>&1 || (echo "File is not gzipped."; false) ) && mv "<cache>/<dest>_tmp" "<cache>/<dest>" 2>&1 )
error_cmd = ( rm -f "<cache>/<dest>_tmp"; echo "Can't get <uri>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" )
post_dl_cmd = $check_cmd || $error_cmd 


# Fetch methods using diffindex-download:
# -i : ignore missing files
# -q : be quiet
# -n <num> : download full file if more than <num> patches would be necessary
http = diffindex-download -i "<uri>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" <cache>/<dest>
https = diffindex-download -i "<uri>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" <cache>/<dest>
ftp = diffindex-download -i "<uri>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" <cache>/<dest>
# In debtorrent URLs, we have to replace 'debtorrent' by 'http', and we always download the full file
debtorrent = diffindex-download -i -n 0 "http://<host>:<port|9988><path>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" <cache>/<dest>

ssh = scp -P <port|22> "<user>@<host>:/<path>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" "<cache>/<dest>_tmp" && $post_dl_cmd
rsh = rcp -l <user> "<host>:/<path>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" "<cache>/<dest>_tmp" && $post_dl_cmd
file = cp "/<path>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" "<cache>/<dest>"
copy = cp "/<path>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" "<cache>/<dest>"
cdrom = echo "Put CDROM labeled <path> in the cdrom device and press [ENTER]" > /dev/stderr ; read DUMMY ; mount "<cdrom>"; cp "<cdrom>/dists/<dist>/Contents-<arch>.gz" "<cache>/<dest>" ; umount "<cdrom>"

# Schemes that might require user input on 'apt-file update'
# These will be skipped if -N is given
interactive = cdrom rsh ssh
```

This is like chinese for me and as I made at least 10 re-instalations off my PC since using Linux, but keep the faith, I won't modify this file alone. I did my best to found information and I  found an explanation saying Synaptic seems to overwritte in this file(??I don't know) which lead to a situation making update and upgrade impossible.
Here this link : http://www.hyjoo.com/sujet-32191.html

Does somebody know what I am suffering off ?

Comment: wish I didn't have to count the line numbers... Can you edit to post a version of the file with line numbers?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the file `apt-file.conf` is finished in the directory `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` instead of the directory `/etc/apt`

Try to move it

```
sudo mv -i /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/apt-file.conf /etc/apt/
```

maybe is better if you check before that it doesn't exist in `/etc/apt` and in case you decide which you want to keep.